# Why does one image swap affect another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am currently trying to get this to work with 2 main-images and accompanying selectors but there will eventually be multiple variants.

My image swap script works and hovering over the thumbnails changes the main-images source to that of the thumbnail, however it changes the main-image of both instead of just the one the thumbnails are grouped with.

Script currently changing both:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Image swap on hover
  $("div.product li img").hover(function() {
    $('img.productimg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
  });
  var imgSwap = [];
  $("div.product li img").each(function() {
    imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
    imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
  });
  $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
}
```

The current html format broken down :

```
<div class="product" class="gallery">
   <div class="mainimage">
      <img class="productimg" src="images/1.jpg" class="main-img">
   </div>
   <div class="imageselector">
      <ul>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/1.jpg"></li>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/2.jpg"></li>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/3.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product" class="gallery">
   <div class="mainimage">
      <img class="productimg" src="images/4.jpg" class="main-img">
   </div>
   <div class="imageselector">
      <ul>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/artwork/artist1/modal/4.jpg"></li>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/artwork/artist1/modal/5.jpg"></li>
         <li><img class="prod-thumbs" src="images/artwork/artist1/modal/6.jpg"></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

From @Terry I have now incorporated this script with the intention of the image selector only effecting the main image which it is grouped/closest too. However this seems to have stopped the hover function from working in any capacity and the only way I have found to get it to work is to revert it back to the previous script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Image swap on hover
  $("div.product li img").hover(function() {
    $(this).closest('.imageselector').prev('.productimg').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
  });
  var imgSwap = [];
  $("div.product li img").each(function() {
    imgUrl = this.src.replace('thumb/', '');
    imgSwap.push(imgUrl);
  });
  $(imgSwap).preload();
});
$.fn.preload = function() {
  this.each(function() {
    $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
  });
}
```

Comment: You're having duplicate IDs in your document: `main-img`. That is not allowed. But that aside, the reason why you are encountering the problem is because whenever you hover the `prod-thumbs` images, it is selecting all the main images. You will want to use DOM traversal so that the thumb images will know which main image source to swap, e.g. `$(this).closest('.imageselect').prev('.mainimage').find('img')`

Comment: @Terry Thanks for the help just need some clarification, I have changed the id's to classes so there's no conflicts there, where does the script you have written go in reference to my existing script?

Comment: That should go in the callback for the hover event. Replace the selector with what I wrote.

Comment: I should note that I'm fairly new to learning JavaScript so I'm still getting to terms with all the lingo and understanding the various complexities of script, sorry to keep asking for specifics, I'm not quite sure what you are referring to  when you say 'callback & selector' @Terry

Comment: @Terry, answers go down there. No one wants to repeat what you said in a proper answer, so it's on you to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue lies with the logic in this block:

```
$("div#gallery li img").hover(function () {
    $('img#main-img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
});
```

Barring the duplciate ID issue aside (you should never recycle IDs in the document, because they have to be unique), the issue you have is that for every gallery image you hover, it will simply select whichever main image jQuery finds in the DOM. What you want is to select the main image that is contextually related to the gallery images: in this case, the main image is nested in `div.mainimage`, which is the sibling of `div.imageselector`, which in turn holds the gallery image. So what you really want is **to select the image element that is nested in the sibling element of the parent of the gallery image**.

To fix your issue, you need to:

1. Change your `gallery` and `main-image` from ID to classes
2. Implement the following code in your hover function:

   ```
   $("div.gallery li img").hover(function () {
       $(this).closest('.imageselector').prev('.mainimage').find('img').attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('thumb/', ''));
   });
   ```

The above logic can be broken down as such:

1. Whenever a gallery image is hovered on, select its closest parent that has the class `.imageselector`
2. Get the previous sibling of the closest parent that has a class of `.mainimage`
3. Find the image element inside `.mainimage`
4. Set the attribute as you have done before

Comment: Hi Terry thanks for your help, I have implemented the code as I have updated in my question but it seems that any additions to this block seem to prevent the hover function from working in any capacity. I don't know whether the other blocks need some sort of tweaking to account for the changes to prevent any kind of conflict.

Comment: @ReganBoyce I don't quite understand your comment. Did you replace your original code above with what I've posted, or you simply pasted it in? Did you also swap out the IDs for classes? Update: it looks like you've pasted the code wrongly. I use `prev('.mainimage')` but you used `prev('.productimg')`. Your selector will return nothing, hence the code will not work.

Comment: thanks for spotting that ! works a treat, thanks for all your help.